# Im having a trouble to add locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

Tags: ios, swift

Im having a trouble to add locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

What i expect : popup asking for location permission to user
What heppend : nothing show

Setting : location setting in iphone : never

Plist:

LocationAlwaysAndWhenInuseUsageDescription

LocationAlwaysUsageDescription

LocationWhenInUseUsageDescription

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class NoobNoobVC: BaseVC, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    
    var locationManager: CLLocationManager!

    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
        locationManager.distanceFilter = 5
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            //locationManager.startUpdatingHeading()
        }
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1620562-requestwheninuseauthorization) says:

> You may call `requestWhenInUseAuthorization()` whenever the current authorization status is not determined (`CLAuthorizationStatus.notDetermined`).

&

> If the initial authorization status is anything other than `CLAuthorizationStatus.notDetermined`, this method does nothing and doesn't call the `locationManager(_:didChangeAuthorization:)` method.

You have to use [`authorizationStatus()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1423523-authorizationstatus) to check the authorization status and then take a proper action like - inform the user what's wrong, ... and what can be done about it. You can call `requestWhenInUseAuthorization()` only if it's `.notDetermined`. This class function is marked as deprecated and if you're targeting iOS >= 14.0 you should use the [instance variant](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/3563952-authorizationstatus).